# Update certain columns of dataframe with other dataframe based on condition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update certain columns of one dataframe with other dataframe based on condition but it is not updating. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Example:

```
The below columns need to be updated-
column_list = ['File Name', 'File Type', 'Published Date', 'Program Name', 'Link']

df1:

Project Number|File Name|File Type|Published Date|Program Name|Link|PDF File Name|Start_dt|End_dt|Is_active|pdf_lst_mod_flg|Indication|rec_created_dt|PDF_File_Name
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_20210416.pdf|2021-04-20||A|N|Hodgkins Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression postASCT |2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_20210226.pdf|2021-03-01|2021-04-20|I|||2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_pt_20210416.pdf|2021-04-20||A|N|Hodgkins Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression postASCT |2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_pt_
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_20210416.pdf|2021-04-20||A|N|Hodgkins Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression postASCT |2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_20210226.pdf|2021-03-01|2021-04-20|I|||2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_
```

df2:

```
Project Number|File Name|File Type|Published Date|Program Name|Link|PDF File Name|Indication|PDF_File_Name
PC0116-000|Brentuximab (Adcetris) HL (post-ASCT) Resubmission – Patient Group COI Declarations|COI Declarations|February 21, 2018|Oncology Pharmaceuticals|https://www.cadth.ca/sites/default/files/pcodr/pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post-asct_resub_coi_pt.pdf|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_pt_20210514.pdf|Hodgkins Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression post-ASCT|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_pt_
```

final Ouput

df1:

```
Project Number|File Name|File Type|Published Date|Program Name|Link|PDF File Name|Start_dt|End_dt|Is_active|pdf_lst_mod_flg|Indication|rec_created_dt|PDF_File_Name
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_20210416.pdf|2021-04-20||A|N|Hodgkins Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression postASCT |2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_
**PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_20210226.pdf|2021-03-01|2021-04-20|I|||2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_fdk_sgi_
PC0116-000|Brentuximab (Adcetris) HL (post-ASCT) Resubmission – Patient Group COI Declarations|COI Declarations|February 21, 2018|Oncology Pharmaceuticals|https://www.cadth.ca/sites/default/files/pcodr/pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post-asct_resub_coi_pt.pdf|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_pt_20210416.pdf|2021-04-20||A|N|Hodgkins Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression postASCT |2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_pt_**
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_20210416.pdf|2021-04-20||A|N|Hodgkins Lymphoma at high risk of relapse or progression postASCT |2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_
PC0116-000||||||PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_20210226.pdf|2021-03-01|2021-04-20|I|||2021-03-01|PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_asct_resub_coi_cln_
```

The condition of updation - both the dataframe first match the PDF_File_Name and then select the Is_Active='A' from df1 and update the required columns with df2.

I am using below code but that is not working-

```
column_list = ['File Name', 'File Type', 'Published Date', 'Program Name', 'Link']
df1.loc[df1['PDF_File_Name'].isin(df2['PDF_File_Name']), column_list] = df2[column_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are duplicates in `PDF_File_Name`, so for me working [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) for replace missing values with convert to default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), so possible assign back to original `df1`:

```
#create default index
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)

column_list = ['File Name', 'File Type', 'Published Date', 'Program Name', 'Link']

#convert PDF_File_Name to index for match
df11 = df1.set_index('PDF_File_Name')
df22 = df2.set_index('PDF_File_Name')


mask = df11.Is_active == 'A'
df1[column_list + ['PDF_File_Name']] = (df11.loc[mask, column_list]
                                            .combine_first(df22[column_list])
                                            .reset_index())
```

---

```
print (df1[column_list])
                                           File Name  \
0  PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_a...   
1  PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_a...   
2  PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_a...   
3  PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_a...   
4  PC0116000_pcodr_brentuximab_adcetris_hl_post_a...   

                                           File Type    Published Date  \
0                                                NaN               NaN   
1                                                NaN               NaN   
2  Brentuximab (Adcetris) HL (post-ASCT) Resubmis...  COI Declarations   
3                                                NaN               NaN   
4                                                NaN               NaN   

        Program Name                      Link  
0                NaN                       NaN  
1                NaN                       NaN  
2  February 21, 2018  Oncology Pharmaceuticals  
3                NaN                       NaN  
4                NaN                       NaN
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael Thank you for your comment.. Actually I have to update only Is_Active='A' record only.. As per your code it is updating both the records.

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - Can you check now?

Comment: What is df11 & df22

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - `It is not working properly` - can you explain more?